# How can I use the Canonical Shop?

Tags: canonical

I open the page and log in using my Ubuntu Single Sign on and it asks me for OpenID credentials, but does not give me the opportunity to use my Facebook Account, instead I am given a link to the OpenID website where I'm invited to pay $29 and give them personal info. 
I'd like to use the Canonical shop, but it doesn't seem possible.
Please may I have any ideas?

Comment: you can't create login here? https://login.launchpad.net/

Comment: Zanna, Thank you for your reply, but I've entered and reentered my details on that page several times, until I gave up and thought I must ask other Ubuntu users. Bob

Comment: Do I need to add SHH keys? Where do I get them from?

Comment: No.  You don't have to get an ssh key.  By the way, the https://shop.canonical.com appears to currently be down.  I get an error: `The shop.canonical.com page isn’t working shop.canonical.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500`, when logging it.  The initial site comes up.  But it gives the error when logging in.  I tried two different computers and two different browsers.

Comment: It opens correctly now. And the Ubuntu SSO should be enough to login.

Comment: At present the store appears to be in a login loop.  It has message on the screen that includes: `Presently we are experiencing technical issues which may prevent some users from loggining in.`  This is just for your information if you are still having problems.  I used the `Contact Us` option on the screen to report the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'm still trapped in the loop. I've emptied my browser cache and made sure cookies are accepted but no joy. 
It does seem as the screen message states that it is only some users who are having this trouble. 
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As per your the comments you don't have to use an SSH key.  Your Ubuntu One `SingleSignOn`is sufficient for logging into the Canonical Shop.

I'm in communications with `Canonical Store Customer Service`.  They have advised me they are having issues that they are trying to resolve and will notify me when it's resolved.

I'll update this answer when I receive the notification.

By the way, they have been sending me updates every few hours since yesterday.

**Update**

For your information, the problem at Canonical show as been resolved as of this morning:

From The Canonical shop:

> Hi Larry
>
> Hope you had a lovely weekend.
>
> Just a quick email to advise that my IT department has now rectified
>   this issue and you should now be able to log in with no issues.
>
> Thank you again for your patience.
>
> Kind Regards
>
> Lauren
>
> Canonical Store Customer Service
>
> [image: Inline images 2]
>
> [image: Inline images 1]